# AngularJS $http.post responses activated much faster if periodic $rootScope.$digest in effect

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In our very large and quite complex AngularJS application, I noticed (by accident!) that a line like this in my main module setup...

```
application.run(function($rootScope) {
    window.setInterval( () => { $rootScope.$digest(); }, 1000);
});
```

...has significant positive impact, in the activation time of our $http.post requests.

A small part of our code that deterministically reproduces the behaviour is this:

```
// In the partial
<button ... ng-click="buttonHandler" ...>

// In the controller
$scope.buttonHandler = function() {
    $http.post(....).success( function() { console.log("Activated"); })
}
```

- We associate a button's ng-click handler with invocation of one of our web services.
- The web service itself responds within 30ms (according to Chrome developer tools).
- However, the code inside the `.success` handler is executed after 1.75 - 2.3 seconds (and only then is the message "Activated" displayed in the console).

However, when we put the *Eternal rootScope $digest Hack (TM)* in place, the activation occurs in less than a second! :-)

I can only guess that the rootScope $digest somehow 'triggers' the actual invocation of the *.success* handler, and since the webservice itself responds in 30ms, the activation time depends on when the button press happens to fall in the 1 second period of the hack's *setInterval*.

I am not saying that this is a recommended practise - but i was very surprised to see it happen. Note that there are no console errors logged or any other mischief reported anywhere in my assertive checks - the code works fine with or without the hack, but with significantly improved performance when the hack is in place.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises in Angular queue up a callback with `$rootScope.$evalAsync(callback)`.

1. The callback checks to see whether the promise has been resolved/rejected.
2. `$evalAsync` schedules the task to run after the next digest cycle is complete.

Therefore, if you're preemptively asking for a digest cycle, your promise may be resolved quicker.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L175